# Ionic drop down IOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, json, ionic-framework, drop-down-menu

I have the following json

> [{"name":"Male","code":"1"},{"name":"Female","code":"2"}]

```
<label id="labelPersonalInformationExtra" class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span id="inputLabel" class="input-label">Gender</span>
    <select id="dropDownPersonalDetails"  ng-options="gender.name for gender in genders"  ng-model="gender" ng-change="updateGender(gender)"  >
    <option  style="display:none;" value="" disabled>{{genderPlaceholder}}</option>
    </select>
    </label>
```

What I wanted to do is have the placeholder to show the last option they chose but what happens is that the value becomes duplicated. If their last selected choice was female. The drop down would show as:

- Female
- Female
- Male

How do I point their selected value to a value in my json so the drop down shows directly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added option for placeholder will remain as is, you can't remove it dynamically. I'd rather prefer to give a generic text to placeholder of `select` like `Select a gender`. And then for preselected `Female` option you could do `$scope.gender = $scope.genders[1]` inside your controller.

**Markup**

```
<label id="labelPersonalInformationExtra" 
  class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span id="inputLabel" class="input-label">Gender</span>
    <select id="dropDownPersonalDetails" ng-model="gender" 
       ng-change="updateGender(gender)"
       ng-options="gender.name for gender in genders">
       <option value="" disabled>Select a gender</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

[**Demo Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/UZQFF9EDudpiOJrtX1sA?p=preview)